How to use EcuMWakeupSource which is not related to a ComM
I have defined wakeup sources in EcuMWakeupSource for which the parameter EcuMComMChannelRef is empty (=> there is no relationship to any ComM channel).
Now I am trying to set such a wakeup source by calling EcuM_SetWakeupEvent() but it won't add the wakeup source to the internal variable for validated wakeup Sources (which can be retrieved by calling EcuM_GetValidatedWakeupEvents()).
Even using a EcuMValidationTimeout won't improve the situation as EcuM_ValidateWakeupEvent() will still never set the (internal) flag for validated wakeup.
This behavior/implementation is actually correct, as it satisfies the requirements:
[SWS_EcuM_02790] EcuM_ValidateWakeupEvent shall return without effect for all sources except communication channels when called while the ECU Manager module is in the RUN state.(SRS_ModeMgm_09145)
[SWS_EcuM_02791] EcuM_ValidateWakeupEvent shall have full effect in any ECU Phase for those sources that correspond to a communication channel (see [SWS_EcuM_02645]).(SRS_ModeMgm_09145)
Now, my Question is: How can I use wakeup sources in EcuM which are NOT related to any ComM channel (so that they get marked as validated wakeup)?

Specification of ECU State Manager, AUTOSAR CP R23-11
7 Functional Specification
…
„It was always intended that wakeup source handling take place not only during wakeup but continuously, in parallel to all other EcuM activities. This functionality is now fully decoupled from the rest of ECU management via mode requests.”

I think it is possible to set the wake up source other than COM.
Some possible cases, I could think of where this could happen,

EcuM_SetWakeupEvent does not accept (wake up) event based on enabled wake up sources and modes.
[SWS_EcuM_04138] dEcuM_SetWakeupEvent shall ignore all events passed in the
sources parameter that are not associated to the selected sleep mode.c()

In Go Sleep state transition, the API EcuM_EnableWakeupSources is not called with appropriate sleep source?


[SWS_EcuM_02389] dTo set the wakeup sources up for the next sleep mode, the
ECU Manager module shall execute the EcuM_EnableWakeupSources callout (see
[SWS_EcuM_02546] ) for each wakeup source that is configured in EcuMWakeupSourceMask for the target sleep mode.c

Thank you for your feedback. But none of your cases does apply here. As I tried to explain: WakeupSources which are not related to any ComM channel never appear as validated wakeups.

It would be interesting to know what happens when EcuM_CheckValidation API is called? May be wakeup source is not getting validated. There is a example in 7.6.4 Activities in the WakeupValidation Sequence in ECU state manager specification

EcuM_CheckValidation() is code to be added by the integrator. But basically, the idea is that from there you call EcuM_ValidateWakeupEvent().
I can tell you that the code implementation (for EcuM_ValidateWakeupEvent()) from Vector is just ignoring any WakeupSources which are not related to any ComM, just as specified by AUTOSAR (which I explained in my original post)
